# Syntax for Windows key in Bootstrap 3s <kbd> syntax

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to print some Windows key combinations with Bootstrap and the `<kbd>`-Tag. Is there a way to print a Windows symbol for the Windows host key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem the `<kbd>` tag from Bootstrap only adds a special style to the text you put in it to make it look like a key. Looking online it would seem there is unfortunately no Unicode character for the Windows logo in regular fonts. The best I was able to find looking quickly online is to use the Wingdings font and input the character #255 (makes `ÿ`with a regular font). However, if you want to use Font-Awesome, their icon collection contains a much better Windows logo (the one from Wingdings looks straight out of Windows 95). I believe this would be your best bet.

TL;DR : if you use Font-Awesome, put a Windows glyph icon from the FA collection inside a `<kbd>` tag and it should work.

Comment: Thank you. Btw. Nice Alienware head